# Customizing navigation bar and its buttons

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Hey I have made a background in adobe photoshop which I would like to use on my UINavigationBar, but there doesn't seem to be any pre made way to do so. I have looked to some articles regarding that, but most of them seemed a bit confusing and some looked very outdated. So could someone enlighten me, how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to set the background on the actual navigation bar itself?  Like where the back button is?

Comment: Yes, the navigation bar and I also would like to know how I customize the buttons on the bar, like the back button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported way to do this is to create a custom subclass of `UINavigationBar` and implement `drawRect:` in that custom subclass to draw your image.

Then, in Interface Builder you should set up a nib with a `UINavigationController` in it - select the `UINavigationBar` instance in that nib and set its custom class to your subclass. When you load the `UINavigationController` from the nib, your `UINavigationBar` subclass will be loaded instead.

Answer (score 0):

The back button is automatically titled by default as the same title as the previous navigation item, or what you set to the `backItem` property on the navigation bar.  You can also specify a `leftBarButtonItem` on the navigation bar for what  you want to display there.  There is also a `rightBarButtonItem` if you want a button in the top right.

As for customizing the drawing, Chris Parker has the right answer there with subclassing it and override the `drawRect:` method